# How can I send a javascript object and form data $.post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a javascript object along with some form data using the short hand $.post().

I am trying to combine the 2 together but having a hard time doing so. Also how would i be able to retrieve the form data in my php page?

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

```
$("#copy_options").on("click", function(){

    $.post("copyOptions.php",{menu_item_ids : item_ids} $("#optionsMenu").serialize(); )

        .fail(function(){
           // console.log("Ajax Failed");
        })


        .done(function () {

            //console.log("Ajax has been complete");

        });


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#copy_options").on("click", function(){
  var dataObj={
     serializeData:$("#optionsMenu").serialize(),
    menu_item_ids :item_ids
}
    $.post("copyOptions.php",dataObj )

        .fail(function(){
           // console.log("Ajax Failed");
        })


        .done(function () {

            //console.log("Ajax has been complete");

        });


    });
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply. But it still doesn't work. I get a bunch of these errors

`SyntaxError: invalid object initializer
index.p...d=21488 (line 475, col 140)
SyntaxError: missing } after property list
index.p...d=21488 (line 475, col 106)
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
index.p...d=21488 (line 475, col 105)
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
index.p...d=21488 (line 475, col 105)
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
index.p...d=21488 (line 475, col 105)`

Comment: in console not sended your data?

Comment: Hey Sorry. You can disregard that. I had my console information on persist. I will try again and let you know

Comment: send me you post in consel?